# how to add two list to make a new matrix

Tags: python, list, sorting, pairwise

i want to append two list as in order to do a pair wise sort of elements `[[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [4, 2], [4, 1]]` to make as `[[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [4, 1], [4, 2]]`

it may be that i append two list `[4,1]` and `[4,2]` into a new list but `a.append(list)` gives `[4, 2, [4, 1]]` . how can i do a pair wise sort or append `list[1]=[4,2]` and
`list[2]=[4,1]` as in order to get `newlist as [[4,1],[4,2]]` instead of `[4, 2, [4, 1]]` also how to do pair wise sort on them directly without appending if the list is as `[[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [4, 2], [4, 1]]` to `[[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [4, 1], [4, 2]]`

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify where you stuck.

Comment: i tried `list1=[4,1]
list2=[4,2]
list2.append(list1)` it gives `4, 2, [4, 1]]`

Comment: @albert but i want output as `[[4,2],[4,1]]` a 2D matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a list of lists, so try this:

```
In [1]: list1 = []

In [2]: list1.append([1,2])

In [3]: list1.append([3,4])

In [4]: list1.append([3,2])

In [5]: list1
Out[5]: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 2]]
```

And sorted:

```
In [6]: sorted(list1)
Out[6]: [[1, 2], [3, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: In addition to @Johannes answer: There is a `reverse` argument for [`sorted`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) which is quite handy if output needs to be in opposite order: `sorted(list1, reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using `pandas`, you can import your array into a pandas DataFrame, and then sort by elements. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [4, 2], [4, 1]])
df.sort([0,1],inplace=True)
print(df.values)
array([[-1, -1],
       [-1, -1],
       [ 4,  1],
       [ 4,  2]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Using `pandas` seems to be somekind of overkill for the given task.

Comment: how to do it without using pandas?

Comment: because it takes me to download modules!

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it's not clear if the pairs are sorted together or separately

## Sort pairs together

```
>>> matrix = [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [4, 2], [4, 1]]
>>> sorted(matrix)
[[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [4, 1], [4, 2]]
```

## Sort pairs separately

You can use `zip` to transpose your matrix, `sorted` to sort the rows and `zip` to transpose your sorted rows back into the matrix:

```
>>> zip(*matrix)
[(-1, -1, 4, 4), (-1, -1, 2, 1)]
>>> [sorted(row) for row in zip(*matrix)]
[[-1, -1, 4, 4], [-1, -1, 1, 2]]
>>> zip(*[sorted(row) for row in zip(*matrix)])
[(-1, -1), (-1, -1), (4, 1), (4, 2)]
```

With another matrix as input, the difference becomes clearer:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> sorted(matrix)
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1]]
>>> zip(*[sorted(row) for row in zip(*matrix)])
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: final output is list of tuples instead of list of list, not sure if it matters, but just wanted to point out

Comment: @nanojohn: Thanks. More important would be to know how the sorting should be applied. The input data doesn't make it clear.